# uploadArchives not honoring subproject archiveName

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, nexus

I have the root project build.gradle as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
allprojects {
    sourceCompatibility=1.7 
    targetCompatibility=1.7

    apply plugin: 'maven'   
    project.version = "0-SNAPSHOT" 
    group = "com.org.abc"   

    uploadArchives {                
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                repository(url:"${nexusURL}") {
                    authentication(userName: "userName", password: "password")
                }
                snapshotRepository(url: "${nexusURL}") {
                    authentication(userName: "userName", password: "password")
                }                   
            }
        }
    }
}
war{
....//generates war file
archiveName "abc-${project.version}.war"
}
```

The subproject(say, folder name is demo) build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: "war"

war {
    from "src/app"        
    archiveName "subProject.war"
}
```

when I run `gradle build` from root project both the war files are created with the given `archiveName`. But for `gradle uploadArchives`, the subproject war is created in nexus as demo-0-SNAPSHOT.war instead of subProject.war. 
How do I achieve to create subProject.war in nexus?